# Built-in Support for String -> Trait?

Tags: scala, traits

Given the following:

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> case object Bip extends Foo
defined module Bip

scala> case object Bar extends Foo
defined module Bar
```

Is there any feature, built into Scala, that can make a `Foo` from a `String`?

example:

`f("Bip")` === `Bip`

`f("Bar")` === `Bar`

`f("...")`  === Exception (or maybe returns `None`)?

Comment: Might you want to consider using an enumeration - either [the Scala library implementation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) or any other with support for f(name):object?

Answer (score 2):

You could use macros, but it may be easier to just use simple Java reflection:

```
namespace org.example

import scala.util.control.Exception._

object Demo extends App {
  sealed trait Foo
  case class Bar() extends Foo
  case class Bip() extends Foo

  def makeFoo(s: String): Option[Foo] = {
    catching(classOf[Exception]).opt(Class.forName("org.example.Demo$" + s).newInstance.asInstanceOf[Foo])
  }

  println(makeFoo("Bar")) // Some(Bar())
  println(makeFoo("Bip")) // Some(Bip())
  println(makeFoo("Bop")) // None
}
```

If you put all the case classes in a single object container like I did above, the class names should be pretty predictable.

Edit: Added optional wrapper for exceptional cases.