# String -> Case Object using Reflection?

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
package com

object Foo {
    trait Parent
    case object Boy extends Parent
}
```

How can I make a method of type: `String -> Option[Foo.Parent]`?

I tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
scala> import com._
import com._

scala> Class.forName("com.Foo$")
res0: Class[_] = class com.Foo$

scala> Class.forName("com.Foo.Boy$")
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Foo.Boy$
```

I referenced this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28785056/409976) since it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: As a user of Java and Clojure, but not Scala, I would expect that class to be named `com.Foo$Boy$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
val classVal=Class.forName("com.Foo$Boy$")
```

To instantiate:

```
val constructor=classVal.getDeclaredConstructor()
constructor.setAccessible(true)
val instance = constructor.newInstance()
```

Comment: ah yes - thanks. `com.Foo.Boy.getClass
res4: Class[_ <: com.Foo.Boy.type] = class com.Foo$Boy$`

Comment: Note that I can't create a new `Foo` though using: `Class.forName("com.Foo$").newInstance`. The error is: `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class  can not access a member of class com.Foo$ with modifiers "private"`

Comment: could you please say more, @Others? I see that `Field#setAccessible` exists, but not sure how to use it here.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I added some code! (Its not tested, so beware typos :p)

Comment: Note that this will actually create a new instance instead of returning the existing object.

Comment: Alexey, how would I return the instance then?